# More efficient regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am an amateur with regular expressions, but I have a need to extract a piece of string in javascript.

My current (working) code is:

```
var txt='Icon/something/0.gif';

var re1='.*?';
var re2='(?:[a-z][a-z]+)';
var re3='.*?';
var re4='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))';

var p = new RegExp(re1+re2+re3+re4,["i"]);
var m = p.exec(txt);
var word = m[1]; //something
```

However I can't imagine that us the most efficient way of doing it.

What I need to do is extract "something" from a string like this:

```
Icon/something/0.gif
```

or "somethingelse" from:

```
Icon/somethingelse/10.gif
```

Is there a more compact regex I can use?

Comment: Sounds like [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: RegExp flags are strings, not arrays, and unless you have a dynamic "selector", there's no reason to manually construct RegExps like that instead of using a simple literal. Finally, the exec() method is rarely used for a few long-winded reasons; i suspect you would find "".match() or "".split() more to your liking.

Comment: Logically, the regex you build is completely equivalent to `[a-z][a-z].*?([a-z][a-z]+)`. Your are extracting the first substring  made of lower-case letters that follows two lower-case letters and one or more arbitrary characters. To me, that seems to be not exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this to get the second element split by the forward slashes (`/`):

```
txt.split("/")[1]
```

Comment: Other answers are correct but I like this solution better...can't believe I didn't think of this. Thanks!

Comment: -1, This way doesn't check if the format is correct (i.e. `Icon/WhatYouNeedToFind/Integer.gif`)

Answer (score 0):

```
/\/([^\/]*)\//
```

will find the first substring of non-/-characters that is surrounded by / characters.

Answer (score -1):

Using substring:

var get=string.substring(string.indexOf("Icon/")+5,string.indexOf("/",string.indexOf("Icon/")+5))

Where string would be Icon/anythingHere/10.gif

Comment: `var a = string.indexOf('/'); var b = string.indexOf('/',a+1); var result = string.substr(a+1,b-a-1);`